# Зачем в ссылке на картинку передавать параметр?

Tags: html

Допустим в HTML коде есть такая ссылка /tratata/kartinka.png?v=777, не совсем понимаю, роль параметра v, где он может использоваться?

Comment: Обычно сервер распознаёт такой запрос, как GET запрос. Парсит название файла и берёт значение GET параметра  - в данном случае `v`. Этот параметр может содержать любого рода информацию. Размер изображения, к примеру.

Comment: @LEQADA ну да, логично, что-то затупил, спасибо)

Comment: Где и как он будет использоваться, решает разработчик сайта